# Calculated Field Forms Plugin Wordpress - Make field output black if = 0; red if <0; green if >0

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I've set up a calculator using the `Calculated Fields Form Plugin` on my `Wordpress` website. For some of the output fields on the calculator I would like it so the value 0 appears black, negative values (anything less than 0) appear red, and positive values (anything greater than 0) appear green.

I'm not a PHP, CSS expert - just sort of attempt to learn as I go or need it - so would be grateful if can bare that in mind with any answers please :)

I can already successfully use `CSS` to change the design of the calculator and specific fields based on the instructions here:

[See Design section and the question "How can I apply CSS styles to the form fields?"](https://cff.dwbooster.com/faq)

I've attempted to add a function via the Code Snippets plugin (which I understand adds to the functions.php file) to be able to do what I need but unsuccessfully.

PHP function code snippet:

```
    $AAcolor = "#353535";

    if (($v < 0))
       $AAcolor = "#ec0909";
    else if (($v > 0))
       $AAcolor = "#FF9900";
```

*CSS class* (for the `Customize Form Design` in the `Form Settings` section of the calculator):

```
    .specialclass input[type="text"],
    .specialclass input[type="number"],
    .specialclass input[type="date"],
    .specialclass input[type="email"],
    .specialclass input[type="password"],
    .specialclass textarea,
    .specialclass select {color: $AAcolor !important;}
```

Then I just add the `css class` `specialclass` to the individual fields Add Css Layout Keyword

I think there is possibly something wrong with the php function I've done or the way I'm getting it to appear in the CSS?

If I change the color in the CSS for example from `$AA` color to `red` that works fine.

So it's really how do I make a PhP function for what I need and then get it to appear using the above CSS. Thanks.

Comment: color: $AAcolor !important should be color: <?php echo $AAcolor; ?> !important

Comment: Thanks. Unsuccessful using the following (hopefully I did how you meant): .specialclass input[type="text"],
.specialclass input[type="number"],
.specialclass input[type="date"],
.specialclass input[type="email"],
.specialclass input[type="password"],
.specialclass textarea,
.specialclass select {color: <?php echo $AAcolor; ?> !important;}

Comment: That syntax is correct, assuming you're putting it directly into a .php file. If you're putting it into some WordPress interface, it's probably stripping the PHP code. If the plugin has a section for you to add CSS, it likely does not honor PHP code within it, for security reasons.

Comment: Ok thanks for this - that's helpful. Likely explains why it won't work. at least I got the function correct in the first place :D. Thanks all again.